# Having $S_n$ being a sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$) random variable, where does $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converge to?

Tags: binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

In our lecture, we learned about the CLT and we were shown the following application:

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ ~ $B(p)$, meaning that $P(X_i = 1) = p \in (0,1)$. Additionally, let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent and identically distributed. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, then (knowing the moment-conditions are fulfilled), the following convergence holds:

$\frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \longrightarrow N(0,1)$

Since $E[S_n] = np$ and $Var(S_n)=np(1-p)$ with $N(0,1)$ denoting a  standard-normal.

Since also the following equation holds:

$\frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{n}} \longrightarrow N(0,p(1-p))$

I was wondering if (or why?) $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \longrightarrow N(p,p(1-p))$  is also a right expression.

Having $E[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}] = \sqrt{n}p$, I do not understand why the expectation of the asymptotic normal distribution should be simply p (which is what my lecturer told us).

Can anyone please help out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{n}} =\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n}p$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N\left(0,p(1-p)\right)$ as $n$ increases,

and $\sqrt{n}p$ increases without bounds as $n$ increases,

you will have    $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverging to $+\infty$.

What your lecturer may have said is that $\frac{S_n}{n} \to p$ in probability and almost surely.  This is the law of large numbers; note there is no square root in the denominator.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is actually what I guessed. Anyway, do you also have a specific reason for having $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ diverging to $\infty$?

Comment: @McSchnürsenkel180 In a handwaving sense $S_n$ is about $np \pm 2\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ so $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ is about $\sqrt{n}p\pm 2\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ which grows without bound as $n$ increases

Comment: Thanks again - so what you say is that assuming $n$ is "large enough", $S_n$ will approximately be bounded as following: $np - 2\sqrt{np(1-p)} \leq S_n \leq np + 2\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ or heuristically, $S_n$ will approx. be bounded by an interval centered around $np$, with "width" determined by the variance?

Comment: I think I got you now. $\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ will approximately always be in [-2,2] meaning that $P(\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)} \in [-2,2])  = 1$  a.s..

Comment: Not almost sure, but with probability of about $95\%$.  And with width related to the standard deviation (square root of the variance)